# How to specify the position and layout of a JFreeChart chart legend

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart to render a stacked area chart. By default, the chart legend is rendered below the plot with the elements laid out horizontally. I would like the legend to appear on the right of the plot with the elements laid out as a vertical list.

Is this possible and, if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A little more time examining the API would have given me the answer:

```
LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equivalent for older versions:

```
    StandardLegend legend = new StandardLegend();
    legend.setPreferredWidth(100);
    legend.setAnchor(Legend.EAST);
    jfreechart.setLegend(legend);
```