# The position of legend in XYLineChart

Tags: java, swing

The position of legend in `XYLineChart` is at the bottom in my application, but I need the legend to be at the top of the graph (in Swing).

[image]

Comment: Which graph API is being used to draw the chart?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to specify the position and layout of a JFreeChart chart legend*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4968852/230513).